# Using service data in component's template - is it a good practice?

Tags: angular

I inject service into component. That service is some kind of data register - all needed components' data is there.

Is this a good practice to use that service data in components' template? Or I should write multiple Observables?

example:

`<my-comp [page]="myService.page" [pageSize]="myService.pageSize"></my-comp>`

Components are always binded to specific services and should not be used somewhere else.

**Edit:** Other way is to define new Subjects in service and subscribe to them in component:

`page = new Subject<number>();` `pageSize = new Subject<number>();`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.page=this.myService.page.subscribe(page=>this.page=page);
    this.pageSize=this.myService.pageSize.subscribe(pageSize=>this.pageSize=pageSize);
}
```

Lot's of uneeded code in my opinion.

Comment: What other ways are you thinking about?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, changes to `myService.page` will not be picked up. You would be better off publishing an observable from the service and then writing `myService.page | async`. Personally, I would prefer to create a copy of this in the component's `ngOnInit`, such as `this.page = this.myService.page`, and then refer to it in the template as `page | async`.

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya Post edited.

Comment: @torazaburo changes are picked up.

Comment: @piernik second one is better I think

Comment: @piernik, yeah, changes will be picked up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is subjective, but here is the perspective from the performance standpoint. The way you use it now will generate the following [updateDirectives](https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-property-bindings-update-in-angular-39c0812bc4ce) function:

```
function (_ck, _v) {
    var _co = _v.component;
    var currVal_0 = _co.myService.page;
    var currVal_1 = _co.myService.pageSize;
    ...
    _ck(_v, 1, 0, currVal_0, currVal_1, ...);
},
```

As you can see the values will be queried on each change detection cycle. The more performant way would be to provide this service to the child component and setup observables in the `ngOnInit`:

```
class MyComp {
    const cancelSubscription = new Subject();
    ngOnInit() {
       this.service.page.takeUntil(cancelSubscription).subscribe((v)=>this.page=v)
       this.service.pageSize.takeUntil(cancelSubscription).subscribe((v)=>this.pageSize=v)
       ...
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
       this.cancelSubscription.next();
       this.cancelSubscription.complete();
```

In this way the function generated by the compiler will look like this:

```
function (_ck, _v) {
    var _co = _v.component;
    var currVal_0 = _co.myService;
    _ck(_v, 1, 0, currVal_0);
},
```

which will perform only one quick comparison by the reference.

An even better approach would be to use DI. Define a service in the parent component and inject it into the `MyComp`:

```
@Component({providers:[Service]})
class ParentComponent
    constructor(private s: Service) {}
    ...
    s.page.next(3)

class MyComp {
    constructor(private s: Service) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      ...
```

So the component will be used like this:

```
<my-comp></my-comp>
```

And in this way the `udpateDirectives` function will not be generated by the compiler at all.

Comment: Yes, but your `subscribe` approach will require the subscribers to also be torn down in `ngOnDestroy`. Is there some reason not to subscribe in the template with `async`?

Comment: @torazaburo, yeah, that's correct, I'll add this information. Thakns